# Continuity of sections after chapter beginning in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

Is there any way the main chapter page (say chapter 1) is followed immediately with the Section 1.1 title and text, without change of page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `_output.yml` file

remove `split_by` line

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
#  split_by: section
```